# How can I increase the resolution of a text in a PNG file?

Tags: pdf, resolution, png

I have images (PNG) with text in them, but if you were to zoom it would become pixelate. How can I fix this?

I even have a [PDF where if you zoom as much as you can you still can't see the pixels](https://d1.islamhouse.com/data/ar/ih_books/single_01/ar_Mushaf_madinah_new_true.pdf). But if you were to convert these images to a PDF you still won't see them the same way you would see that [PDF](https://d1.islamhouse.com/data/ar/ih_books/single_01/ar_Mushaf_madinah_new_true.pdf). Basically, I want to turn those images to a PDF the same as the this [PDF](https://d1.islamhouse.com/data/ar/ih_books/single_01/ar_Mushaf_madinah_new_true.pdf). How can I do this?

I also tried contacting them and also the company (Dar Almaarifa) behind the Mushaf and neither responded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The short answer is, you cant.

PNG is a raster graphics format, while (in your example) the PDF is a vector graphics format.  Raster images have a fixed resolution.  If you scale them up or down, they will lose quality.  If you want an image that can be scaled bigger or smaller, without loss of quality, it has to be done in a vector format.

Comment: PDFs can contain raster images. Many horrible ones do. But generally, text in a PDF is a vector image.

Comment: Don't you mean "**Raster** images have a fixed resolution" not "**Vector** images have a fixed resolution"?

Comment: Yes I know. But I meant how can I do that AFTER I convert it to a PDF?

Comment: @thatonedodobird You cant.

Comment: Then how come could Islam house (I think they're the ones who turned the Mushaf to a PDF) do that?

Comment: Look at this PDF https://d1.islamhouse.com/data/ar/ih_books/single_01/ar_Mushaf_madinah_new_true.pdf

Comment: If you zoom you won't see the pixels

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a raster PNG image - you can create a vector image and screen capture the improved resolution of the vector image displayed in a vector-based program (ie. Inkscape).  Save the screen capture as a raster PNG file and take advantage of the better resolution of the vector image.

Vector Image screen captured to PNG file:

[image: Vector Image screen captured to PNG file]